# Best method to implement an abstract factory pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

Consider following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


// =============================


class Shape{
public:
    virtual ~Shape(){};

    virtual void process() = 0;
};

class Triangle : public Shape{
public:
    virtual void process() override {
        printf("BBB\n");
    }
};


// =============================


/* option 1 */
class TriangleProducer{
public:
    Triangle factory(){
        return Triangle {};
    }
};



/* option 2 */
class PtrShapeProducer{
public:
    Shape *factory(){
        return new Triangle {};
    }
};



/* option 3 */
class PimplShape : public Shape{
    Shape *sh;
public:
    PimplShape(Shape *sh) : sh(sh){
    }

    virtual ~PimplShape() override{
        delete sh;
    }

    virtual void process() override {
        sh->process();
    }
};

class PimplShapeProducer{
public:

    PimplShape factory(){
        return new Triangle {};
    }
};


// =============================


int main(){
    TriangleProducer f1;
    Triangle tri = f1.factory();
    tri.process();



    PtrShapeProducer f2;
    Shape & sh = *f2.factory();
    sh.process();
    delete & sh;



    PtrShapeProducer f3;
    PimplShape psh = f3.factory();
    psh.process();



    return 0;
}
```

**OPTION 1**

It is nice, but it does not really achieve polymorphism. Return type is known and you must match it. One may add `auto` instead of `Triangle`, but this not change anything except easier refactoring.

**OPTION 2**

This is how Java and PHP is doing it. But I understood that "raw" pointers are not desirable in C++. One may add `std::unique_ptr`, but once again this does not change anything, except missing `delete` statement.

**OPTION 3**

This is what someone propose here some time ago - works nice, no "raw" pointers, no delete. But it is so much code, and way too complicated - seems fancy way, but not the correct one.

**OPTION 4** (not implemented here)

Playing with const references - however they are const and it does not change the "factory" return type. I think, this is more like variation, it is not real option.

Any other option I am missing?
Also what would be best option to go?

Comment: Define "Best". Programming is always just tradeoffs, there is no silver bullet.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking for the best way to implement ***a factory pattern***?  "Polymorphism" doesn't seem to be what you're comparing here.

Comment: @DrewDormann - i think both are connected. I am looking for "abstract factory pattern" - e.g. both factory and return class are pure virtual

Comment: What's wrong with returning either Shape or Shape* in option 1 and 2 respectively?

Comment: @BoPersson - best = most accepted practice. I would use a pointer, but everybody around thinks this is "C with Classes"

Comment: @AdamKosiorek - option 1 returns Triangle. It can not be compiled if returns a Shape.

Answer (score 6):

I think the most *idiomatic* modern C++ method is the one you mention in passing but ignore. Return a `std::unique_ptr<Shape>`.

It is safe,  clearly expresses ownership,  supports polymorphism and doesn't need much code.

```
class ShapeFactory {
public:
  std::unique_ptr<Shape> create(){
    return std::make_unique<Triangle>();
  }
};
```

But I wouldn't want to claim it was the "best"  method.

Your `PimplShape` in option 3 is actually very similar to a `unique_ptr` just less generic or tested.

Comment: This solution compared to the option 3 loses the ability to design your own member functions to the handle class, since unique_ptr is coming from the standard library.

Comment: @tp1 All the public member functions of `Shape` are available directly via `operator->`, if you need more functionality than that then sure create your own class.  Although I'm not sure I would call it a "handle class" at that point, it is just a class that is composed of a `Shape` and personally I would still use a `unique_ptr` internally.

Answer (score 0):

Your factories are passing around ownership. There's another alternative to that aspect; instead of passing around ownership, you can make the factory own the objects:

```
   class Factory {
   public:
      ~Factory() { for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++) delete vec[i]; }
      Shape &build_obj() {
         Shape *sh = new Triangle;
         vec.push_back(sh);
         return *sh;
       }

   private:
      void operator=(const Factory &);
      std::vector<Shape*> vec;
   };
```

Comment: This assumes the factory _should_ own the object. You could very well just return a `std;:unique_ptr` and transfer ownership in an obvious and idiomatic way. If you want to express ownership here you might return a const reference to a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @captain obvlious; no, that's where idiomatic c++ went wrong, when they insist on passing around ownership every time.

Comment: That's why I said _might_. Returning a raw pointer is a perfectly acceptable representation of a non-owning pointer, but your post doesn't really touch on any of that.

Comment: One of the benefits of the abstract factory pattern is separating concerns about creation from those about ownership. This pattern has its uses but I don't think it is the abstract factory pattern. It seems a bit restrictive if created objects can't be destroyed until the factory is destroyed.

Comment: @Chris drew: The example above is slightly different that what I normally use. I often have the function return int handles instead of a reference. But since he wanted OO solution, access to the Shape's member functions is important, so that's why it returns a reference. Now there's no way to "delete" the object manually from the container, since there isn't proper handle available. of course void del(Shape &s); would solve the problem of not being able to individually delete objects.