# Is there any issues with this factory pattern implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, factory

Recently I asked following question:

[Best method to implement an abstract factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494734/best-method-to-implement-an-abstract-factory-pattern)

My future research show that you can implement the factory like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <memory>

class Base{
    char x[20000];
};

class Child : public Base{
public:
    Child(int a, int b){

    }
};

std::unique_ptr<Base> factory(){
    return std::unique_ptr<Base> { new Child(5, 6) };
}

int main(){
    Base & a = *factory();

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles without warnings, and it make no memory leak, even `std::unique_ptr` is dereferenced immediately.

Is this `Base & a = *factory();` legitimate and well accepted way to "collect" value from factory?

The only problem I see here would be if `a` variable leave the scope. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Base &a = *factory();
```

You dereferenced the `unique_ptr` and kept the reference to its pointee.
But you didn't store the `unique_ptr` itself.
Thus it dies at the end of the statement, taking its pointee with it, and your reference is now dangling.

Comment: but `Base &a` will be destroyed on same place - end of the scope

Comment: @Nick not the end of the scope -- the end of the *statement*. The semicolon, that is. `a` will be dangling as soon as it's done getting initialized.

Comment: seems only way is: `auto aa = factory(); auto & a = *aa;`

Comment: @Nick Why do you need to "collect" the value into a reference? Why not just use the `std::unique_ptr`? If you need to pass a reference to a function that's fine you can dereference it then.