# what C++ idiom / pattern is this

Tags: c++, decorator, idioms, pimpl-idiom

I am still new to C++11.

Some time ago I asked following question:
[Best method to implement an abstract factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494734/best-method-to-implement-an-abstract-factory-pattern)

In order to research some more, I want to know what is the name of this C++ idiom.

I call it `pimpl` here, but I am not sure if this is the correct name.

The intention of whole thing is to hide the raw or smart pointer when returning Shape object from factory. Using this "pattern" factory will be able to return one and same type, and the specific implementation will be encapsulated inside the object.

It is very similar to `decorator` too, except it does not decorating anything.

One might spot similarity to `adapter` as well, except outside interface is same as "inside" interface.

```
class PimplShape : public Shape{
    Shape *sh;
public:
    PimplShape(Shape *sh) : sh(sh){
    }

    virtual ~PimplShape() override{
        delete sh;
    }

    virtual void process() override {
        sh->process();
    }
};
```

Comment: "when returning Shape object from factory" How is that meant to be done here? You have no methods that return the contained Shape. Also, this will create an entire Shape, that itself has to contain a pointer to another Shape. I'm not sure that's what you want, is it? Seems redundant to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494734/best-method-to-implement-an-abstract-factory-pattern - check this. if this is used, factory will always return one and same type. The specific implementation will be encapsulated in this type.

Comment: What does your class do that unique_ptr doesn't ?

Comment: @Pumkko - this is very good point, it do nothing more, except you do not need to dereference it.

Comment: Forget all those "idioms" and "patterns". None of them is a rule of thumb. The most important rule is the common sense, base on it and your specific case you may come up to a suitable "pattern" yourself.

Comment: @Nick this seems to be something weird and custom:D For `pimp` you wouldn't use `virtual` methods and would not inherit from the base type - you would just wrap the private type and call methods on it (also you can't put the implementations of methods in the header since you need to hide the private type). From the other hand this seems like an non template implementation of CRTP.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that you have cooked up something in between multiple idioms.

The idea of `pimpl` is to hide the inner class that provides the actual functionality so that you can change is as you want without affecting the users (Qt does this extensively). If we look at you your code there are two things than forbid this - the inheritance and the fact that the methods are implemented in the class definition (so the methods of the inner class are visible to the users of the class). In you case a proper `pimpl` would be:

```
// PimplShape.h
class Shape;

class PimplShape
{
    Shape *sh_;
public:
    PimplShape(Shape *sh);
    ~PimplShape();
    void process();
};

// PimplShape.cpp
#include "Shape.h" // Defines Shape::process() so PimplShape can use it

PimplShape::PimplShape(Shape *sh) : sh_(sh)
{

}

PimplShape::~PimplShape()
{
    delete sh_;
}

void PimplShape::process()
{
    sh_->process();
}
```

As you can see here, the `Shape` class is hidden from any users of the `PimplShape.h` file.

If we look at your example from the point of view of the functionality, seems that you want to achieve [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) but this is not the way to do it.

Comment: I don't think it is typical in the Pimpl pattern for the "impl" to be an abstract class (I know from the context of Nick's other question that `Shape` is an abstract class). You don't normally need to hide abstract classes.

Comment: @ChrisDrew this is just to show how `pimpl` would look like with the given code example so that Nick can see the difference:) As I said, what he has seems to be something in between many idioms so there should be some clarification as to what is the goal he is trying to achive.